# Mods often misuse their power

Tags: discussion

Hinduism SE is always full of trash questions. Just open the site at any time and look at the quality of questions. They seem to see no further than caste, gender, and stories of Puranas.

Anyway wherever I try to put some sense into people to make it a better place, I have seen these mods come in the way and bully me. Atleast let me have a discussion on the forum. It doesn't belong to your dad I suppose.

It looks as if mods are unaware about the downvote option. It's there just for that reason. If you don't like my answer, just push it and STOP deleting my comments, questions and answers.

Let me give you an example. There was this question - can women attain moksha? On this question yesterday I just commented - "why ask such a stupid question". I commented on the question because the OP didn't justify why he/she thinks women cannot attain moksha. Today I found out my comment was deleted.

Comment: Lokesh, when you comment on a forum or a website which has rules and norms, you have to abide by it. Using words such as stupid is not the way to comment. The way you have said is under rude category. Understand this. Instead you could have approached the same in a polite manner. Any usage of unfriendly or unkind words will not be accepted here.

Comment: The way one expresses matters. You are just pouring out your emotions. However, when in a public website, it will not fit. Instead express your points in a polite manner.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti How's stupid an unfriendly word? It just means "not sensible", you can look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: Lokesh, the way you said "why ask such a stupid question " is rude towards the person who asked the question. I request you to once again see code of conduct of SE.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Thanks. I just read it. No where do I find though that a comment can be deleted by mod in such a case. I could have simply deleted my comment or rephrased if a mod had told me what you just told me now.

Answer (score 6):

> why ask such a stupid question

If this is your comment then it falls under the "unfriendly or unkind" category. People might also find it as rude. So it's not the moderator's fault if that comment was deleted. It is very likely that users have flagged it.
(It will be good if you can reproduce the full comment here if you can).

> I feel like I am sitting among perverts and bigots

You see your language is far from being acceptable. If you write such posts/comments and mods delete them you can't complain because this is definitely not how you should express yourself on the site.

Comment: I apologize for my second statement which you quoted. Regarding my first statement, I do not understand how calling a question "stupid" is unacceptable on the forum. As far as I know "Stupid" is not a bad word, it just means that the question wasn't an intelligent one.

Comment: @Lokesh "What a stupid question" is definitely not acceptable (it is rude towards the asker). It will be regarded as unfriendly or unkind or even rude. SE has a very strict Code of Conduct guidelines and which don't allow us to make such comments.

Comment: You might be right about this one but what about my other questions and answers which are wrongly marked as duplicate or closed? See for example  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/what-is-the-original-hare-krishna-mahamantra , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49842/jaya-evolution-to-bharat-and-then-to-mahabharat

Even after clarifying that its not a duplicate, the mods don't do anything. They are always fast to close a question or answer rather than having a discussion. That is the most frustrating thing. A mod could have told me my comment sounds bad.

Comment: @Lokesh If you think your question was wrongly closed then you can raise the issue here on Meta. That is the procedure.

Comment: You can have discussions with Mods in the Hinduism chatroom if you feel it's needed @Lokesh

Comment: you are the one who marked my first question as duplicate. Please fix it.

Comment: Oh :D let me see then .... @Lokesh

Comment: I am not the only there are 4 others. But you have already accepted an answer so you are done with it. What is the point of reopening it now? @Lokesh

Comment: why was it closed in the first place? I want an explanation. I might be done with it but there are other people who might have new findings and can provide a better answer. That's the whole point of SE I suppose.

Comment: Then you should post a Meta question asking why the Q was closed? Others can discuss then whether it was right to close it or not. If sufficient number of users agree with you you will have your Q reopened @Lokesh